# Run unit tests from abstract class in D?

Tags: oop, d

I would like to run unit tests from the abstract class instead of from the concrete classes that inherit from it. I tried a few things that would not compile:

```
unittest(this T) { ... }

abstract class Parent(this T) : GrandParent
{
    ...
    unittest
    {
        T x = new T();
        x.something = true;
        assert(x.something == true);
    }
    ...
}
```

Is there something else I can do to de-duplicate the thousands of lines of unit tests that are otherwise going to exist for each child class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're happy with a base class that's specialized (and thus duplicated) for each subclass:

```
abstract class Base(T) {
    static assert(is(T : typeof(this)), "Tried to instantiate "~typeof(this).stringof~" with type parameter "~T.stringof);
    unittest {
        import std.stdio : writeln;
        auto a = new T();
        writeln(a.s);
    }
}

class Derived : Base!Derived {
    string s() {
        return "a";
    }
}
```

Instead of the `static assert`, I'd have preferred to have a template constraint on `Base`, but sadly this doesn't work (when the constraint is tested, we don't yet know if `Derived` inherits from `Base!Derived`, since that only happens after the constraint has passed, of course).

This pattern is known in C++ as [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Comment: Thank you so much! That did not *just* do EXACTLY what I wanted, but it also fixed another problem with my code! You are a wizard, sir!